# Does Cassandra lock files in the data directory during reads/writes?

Tags: file, operating-system, filesystems, cassandra

I know that snapshots can be taken while Cassandra is online. What this does is create a snapshot sub-directory in each column family directory, and places a copy of the column family inside of it. But I don't know if this is possible because there is no file locking at all, or if the snapshot directive is simply waiting for a file to unlock prior to copying it.

Does anyone know how Cassandra interacts with the files in the data directory? Also, is the behavior operating system dependent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, it is important to realise that all files in Cassandra's data directory are write-once.  No file is ever modified, it is created, then eventually merged with others then deleted.  (This is how Cassandra gets such good write performance, since all disk accesses for writes are sequential.)

The other thing is that taking a snapshot does not copy the file, it creates a hard link.  This works because the files are read-only so no copy is necessary.

Because of these, no file locking is necessary.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, according to the DataStax's [documentation](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/operations/backup_restore) : `If JNA is enabled, snapshots are performed by hard links. If not enabled, I/O activity increases as the files are copied from one location to another, which significantly reduces efficiency.`

Comment: Good spot, although unfortunately that documentation is incorrect.  I just confirmed from the source code - the files are never copied, with or without JNA.  The difference is though that without JNA, Cassandra needs to run 'ln' which involves a fork.  This requires (temporarily) enough memory to duplicate Cassandra's memory so can fail even in healthy environments without JNA.  So you should have JNA installed but not to avoid the copy.